# Updating List Item value based on Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, designer-workflow

I have a List which has only Read Permissions for a User Group(let's call it Less). There is other User group(let's call it More) which has full control on this list.

1. I have created a Workflow on this list and also created a Task List.
2. Now after the task is completed by Less Group, Status is updated in
   Task List.
3. Is it possible to Update the Status even in Main List after it
   is updated in Task List because the Less group has got only Read permission.

If it is possible how can I go about doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can update the status in your Main list if you move the update action inside the App Stage.

[image: Any actions placed inside an App Step will have Read/Write permissions to all Items in the site, such as site lists.]

> Any actions placed inside an App Step will have Read/Write permissions
>   to all Items in the site, such as site lists.